# How to build a library using cmake in windows

Tags: cmake

I've tried to build a library (called libiec61850) using cmake in windows. I have installed cmake and configured the "path" environment with the directory where I have installed the cmake. Then, 
1-I created a subfolder called "build" in my library's directory
2- I copy the subfolder directory in the command line and type
   cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" and got many errors as follows:
 - la génération a démarré
 - echec de la build
 - Cmakeoutput.log : "The system is: Windows - 6.1.7601 - AMD64"

See the attached file.

Please, you help will be precious.[error_cmake_windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XopWa.jpg)

Comment: There are [several questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Failed+to+run+MSBuild+command%22) on Stack Overflow with error `Failed to run MSBuild command`. Check them.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked up the library and tried it out myself, and I got it to work.

I normally use NMake to compile Visual Studios programs. If you'd like to use the same, you need to make sure that the MSVC environment is set up properly before using it. I normally run vcvarsall.bat in cmd first like so:

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat
```

You could do the same wherever your vcvarsall.bat file is in your Visual Studio 2015 folders (I used Visual Studio 2017, but it should work fine with Visual Studio 2015 as well).

Next, these were the commands that I used and their respective outputs:

```
D:\Users\patrick\src\vs2017>cd libiec61850

D:\Users\patrick\src\vs2017\libiec61850>mkdir build

D:\Users\patrick\src\vs2017\libiec61850>cd build

D:\Users\patrick\src\vs2017\libiec61850\build>cmake .. -G "NMake Makefiles"
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.11.25547.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.11.25547.0
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503
/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503
/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.255
03/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.255
03/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for clock_gettime in rt
-- Looking for clock_gettime in rt - not found
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
server-example-logging: sqlite not found
-- Generating RC file : D:/Users/patrick/src/vs2017/libiec61850/build/src/version.rc
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR - Failed
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED - Success
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Users/patrick/src/vs2017/libiec61850/build

D:\Users\patrick\src\vs2017\libiec61850\build>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Scanning dependencies of target iec61850
[  0%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/iec61850.dir/common/string_map.c.obj
string_map.c
```

It then continued compiling.

Try all of that out. If you make a build directory, you probably need to 'cd' into it, and then run cmake with a '..' to indicate that the CMakeLists.txt directory is one directory up. Let me know if you can't use NMake or if it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I've followed your suggestions and the building of the library works with VS2017 ! thanks a lot. Now, when I want to use the examples given in the library, i use the same process as before i.e, I create a build subdirectory in one of the examples, then I 'cd' into it and type again: cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" and as a result it creates the build files for the selected example (but in visual studio, normal). What if i would like to get both library and examples directly in python 3.6? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad the build works! It looks like it puts some example executables in build\examples (in the directories there). As for using it with Python, I'm not sure. From their [github page](https://github.com/mz-automation/libiec61850), it says that they have some experimental python bindings that you can build with swig. Building that makes the process a little more complicated. It looks like you can pass the flag -DBUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS=ON when you run cmake, but you would also have to have swig and make sure that libiec61850 can find it when you run cmake.